# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path') on frontend but backend worked with postman

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, formidable

I am writing you today because I'm facing a problem since few days :

I made a Rest API with Express and Express-formidale that is connected to a mongoDB data base totally working on Postman.
I am now trying to consume this API with a React application. I already did the signup and login page which are working perfectly in both front and back. Using the same way to process I did a post route to create some Post, that is working on Postman (screenshot and code below). But I can't make it on the frontend : My input are retrieving the value but I recieved an error 400 from my server **"Bad request" and "data: {message: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')"}"**

Really apreciate a hand on that please guys :)

PS: I am not a native english speaker, sorry for the writing :)

frontend/src/pages/PostForm.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const PostForm = ({ token }) => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    try {
      event.preventDefault();

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("title", title);
      formData.append("image", image);
      formData.append("description", description);

      if (title && image && description) {
        await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/post/publish", formData, {
          headers: {
            authorization: "Bearer " + token,
          },
        });
        navigate.push("/");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
    }
  };

  console.log(image, title, description);
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <p>Ajoute une photos</p>

          <div>
            <div>
              <input
                type="file"
                id="image"
                onChange={(event) => {
                  setImage(event.target.files[0]);
                }}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <h4>Titre</h4>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="title"
              value={title}
              placeholder="ex: Chemise verte"
              onChange={(event) => {
                setTitle(event.target.value);
              }}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <h4>Décris ton article</h4>
            <textarea
              type="description"
              cols="30"
              rows="10"
              value={description}
              placeholder="ex: Porté quelque fois, taille correct"
              onChange={(event) => {
                setDescription(event.target.value);
              }}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">Ajouter</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostForm;
```

backend/routes/post.js

```
router.post("/post/publish", isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { title, description } = req.fields;
    const image = req.files.image.path;

    const newPost = new Post({
      title,
      description,
      owner: req.user,
    });

    const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(image, {
      folder: `5deg/posts/${newPost._id}`,
      public_id: "preview",
    });

    // Add image in newPost
    newPost.image = result;

    await newPost.save();

    res.status(201).json(newPost);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

backend/models/Post.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Post = mongoose.model("Post", {
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  description: String,
  image: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, default: {}, required: true },
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  owner: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
});

module.exports = Post;
```

console screenshot :
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9umqr.png)

Comment: Hi @zMzM, Kindly try printing req, res in backend/routes/post.js.

Once you will print it you might able to figure out it seems image is not getting any value as path as per current situation.

Comment: Hi @Iva Yes I did it and the output is `{}` . and when I do it with postman, i got the good response and the object is save in database. I'm litteraly lost on this one :(

Comment: That means you are not getting anything in req / res and you are still trying to read the same. Please check why you are getting empty value there first.